# menu with fontawesome icons in typo3

Tags: menu, typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.7.x

I try to implement an menu using fontawesome icons in typo3  8.7.13 .
My idea was to extend the table pages with the field tx_fontawesome_icon - no problem - it can be used in the page properties an is also saved in the database.

But how can I use it in the typoscript?

```
[ts]
lib.mainnav_mobile = HMENU
lib.mainnav_mobile {
  wrap = <ul>|</ul>
  1 = TMENU
  1 {
    expAll = 1
    NO = 1
    NO {
      wrapItemAndSub =<li>|</li>
      stdWrap.wrap = <i class="fas fa-home fa-2x"></i>|
      stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
      ATagTitle.field = title
      ATagParams = class="home-link"
    }
  }
}
[/ts]
```

Thanks
Volker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you store the complete iconname in the field. If you might skip the prefix, build the prefix in your wrap.

Your attempt with `.stdWrap` would be possible so I would prefer the property for this: `.before`

You can use something like this (fill in the rest of the menu definition):

```
    :
    NO {
        :
        before.cObject = TEXT
        before.cObject {
            field = tx_fontawesome_icon
            ## have a default icon: 
            ifEmpty = fa_home
            noTrimWrap = |<i class="fas | fa-2x"></i>|
            # if you want the icon to be linked too:
            typoLink.parameter.field = uid
        }
    }
```

use `.noTrimWrap` so you stay with the spaces before and after the icon-name.

---

If the icon should be inside of only one link, you need to add the icon to the item text (page title).

Therefor you use `.stdWrap.wrap` as you started. but you need to build the wrap from a cObject (see above) or use a datawrap:

```
:
NO {
    :
    stdWrap.dataWrap = <i class="fas {field:tx_fontawesome} fa-2x"></i>|
    :
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much - the function is as you expected. But I made a big mistake - the fontawesome icon should be inside the a-tag (too much tests with the code and then copied the wrong :( )
cu
Volker

Comment: answer edited: two possibilities to get a linked icon

Answer (score 0):

the solution for me is:

```
lib.mainnav_mobile = HMENU
lib.mainnav_mobile {
wrap = <ul>|</ul>

1 = TMENU
1 {
    expAll = 1

    NO = 1
    NO {
        wrapItemAndSub =<li>|</li>

        stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
        ATagTitle.field = description // subtitle // title
        ATagParams = class="home-link"
        ATagBeforeWrap = 1
        stdWrap.wrap.cObject = TEXT
        stdWrap.wrap.cObject {
            field = tx_fontawesome_icon
        ## have a default icon:
                ifEmpty = fa-home
            noTrimWrap = |<i class="fas | fa-2x"></i>&nbsp;|
        }
    }
```

Thanks for the help!
Volker